# MIPS code does not print output and goes into an infinite loop

Tags: arrays, assembly, output, mips, infinite-loop

```
.data
input: .space 200 
input_data: .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 
output: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0
result_str: .asciiz ": "
newline_str: .asciiz "\n"
input_end: #marker for the end of the input array

.globl main


.text

main:
    li $v0, 9 #sbrk syscall code
    li $a0, 200 #allocating space for the input array (50 integers * 4 bytes each)
    syscall
    la $a1, input # loads the address of the static input array
    la $a2, input_end # loads the end address of the input address
    la $a3, input_data #loads the address to copy the values.
    
    #copies values from static input array.
    copy_loop:
        beq $a3, $a2, copy_done #exits the loop if the end is reached
        lw $t0, 0($a3) 
        sw $t0, 0($a1)
        addi $a1, $a1, 4 #moves to the next element in the static array
        addi $a3, $a3, 4 #moves to the next step in the memory
        j copy_loop
        
    copy_done:
        
    la $a0, input #$a0 based address of the input array
    li $a1, 12 #$a1 how many numbers are in the array
    la $a2, output #$a2 based address of the output array
    jal countNumbers
    
    #Print result
    la $a0, output #a0 based on the address of the output array
    li $a1, 12 #a1 how many numbers are there in the array.
    jal printResult
    
    #Exit the pogram 
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
    
    
countNumbers :
    li $t0, 0 #initializes the loop counter
    li $t1, 50 #size of the output array
    
count_loop:
    beq $t0, $a1, count_done #if counter == arrayLength, exit the loop
    
    lw $t2, 0($a0) #loads the cirrent number from the input
    jal increaseCnt
    beq $v0, 0, error #checks for any errors.
    
    addi $a0, $a0, 4 #moves to the next element in the array
    addi $t0, $t0, 1 #increments the loop counter
    j count_loop
    
count_done:
    jr $ra
    
error:
    li $v0, 10 #exits the program
    syscall
    

increaseCnt:
    #checks if the num is in valid range (0-49)
    blt $t2, 0, invalid_index
    bge $t2, $t1, invalid_index
    
    lw $t3, 0($a2) #loads the current count from the output
    addi $t3, $t3, 1 #increases the count
    sw $t3, 0($a2) #stores the updated count in output
    
    li $v0, 1 #sets return value to 1; success
    jr $ra
    
invalid_index:
    li $v0, 0 #sets return value to 0; failure
    jr $ra
    

printResult:
    li $t0, 0 #initializes the loop counter
    
print_loop:
    beq $t0, $a1, print_done #if counter == array length, exit the loop

    lw $t4, 0($a0) #loads the current number from the output
    bnez $t4, print_num #skip if count = 0
    
    addi $a0, $a0, 4 #moces to the next element in the output array
    addi $t0, $t0, 1 #increments the loop counter
    j print_loop
    
print_num:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, result_str #loads the address of the result string
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t4 #moves the counter to $a0 for printing
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline_str #loads the address of the newline string
    syscall
    
    addi $a0, $a0, 4 #moves to the next element in the array
    addi $t0, $t0, 1 #increments the loop counter
    j print_loop
    
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
    
print_done:
    jr $ra
```

The above code implements a program that count the numbers in the array. The countNumbers function counts each number in the array. The increaseCnt function checks if the numbers are in the range (0-49) and prints an error message if it isn't. Otherwise, it increments the base address by 1. The printResult prints the result. For instance, in the array arr = {10, 2, 1, 1, 3, 10 , 49}, the output will be:-

Result:
1: 2
2: 1
3: 1
10: 2
49: 1

The main function will call countNumbers() and printResult() to count and show numbers in the array.

I have tried different recommendations that have been suggested on other questions, but none of them have worked and I am still struggling with the issue. This is the first time I have used MIPS to write, so I am still struggling with it.
PS: I am currently using Mars 4.5 for writing the code.

Comment: Get to know your data.  What is the value of `input_end`.  Do you expect your pointer in `a3` to reach that value in `a2` by incrementing by 4?? Hint: it will never match..